# How to delete every row in a range that contains data?

Tags: excel, vba

In a big data set I am trying to find each cell in column J that contains any data so "is not blank", then delete that row that  contains data. My code however won't work for it:

```
Dim rng3 As Range

Do
    Set rng3 = Columns("J:J")
    If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

I was hoping somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select a range you need
2. Press `F5`
3. Press `Special...` button
4. Select `Constants` or `Formulas` (with other selections, if needed)
5. Press `OK`
6. Now go to: `Home` -> `Cells` -> `Delete` (arrow) -> `Delete Sheet Rows`

**UPDATE**

Macros:

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithData()

    Dim rng As Range

    ' Change to the range you need
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    ' Change field to the one you need
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    With rng
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) 'Exclude header
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Rows.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I know this, however I want VBA to do the same in the middle of a macro. It would be really inefficient if I had to stop and do this manually then start another macro to carry on with the process.

Comment: Updated an answer

Answer (score 1):

Several moments:

You test `Range` against being `Nothing` - it will always return `True` because it actually refers to an **object.** To test the contents of the cell, use `IsEmpty()`.

If you are deleting rows, then run the loop **backwards.**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim I As Integer

'You need only non-empty cells, thus the intersection of needed column and used range of your worksheet
    Set Rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("J"))

'Loop the cells backwards, from the last row to the first
    For I = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
'If the cell is not empty, the delete that row and continue upwards
        If Not IsEmpty(Rng.Cells(I)) Then
            Rng.Cells(I).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will do the trick:

```
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 10).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i, 10).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great, can you please explain what "i" stands for in this coding?

Comment: It's just an integer... You could use any other expression... I usually use "i", I don't know why... :D