# Excel changing page break while copying to other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code (see below) to copy certain rows from worksheet A to worksheet B. There are only values in columns A till N, but after copying to worksheet B, excel changes the document printing range to A till column XFD, so while printing the copied worksheet B, there are like +100 blank pages created. I have no clue what causes the problem, I've changed the scrollArea of the worksheet, but still no change in the created print range. Is it possible to lock the print range using VBA to $A:$N?

Copying code included below.

```
Sub Samenvattend()
'
' Samenvattend Macro
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "gedetailleerde meetstaat" Then
MsgBox "Deze macro kan alleen in het werkblad 'gedetailleerde meetstaat' worden toegepast"
Else
Dim a As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("gedetailleerde meetstaat")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("samenvattende meetstaat")

j = 2     ' Start copying to row 2 in target sheet
For Each a In Source.Range("A2:A10000")   ' Do 10000 rows
    If a <> "" Then
       Source.Rows(a.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       Target.Rows(j).Value = Source.Rows(a.Row).Value
       Target.Cells(j, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*RC[-1]"
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next a
End If
```

End Sub

Thanks :)

Comment: The first `If` could be closed by injecting `Exit Sub` after `MsgBox` to avoid `Else`.

Comment: You could change the print area. You are copying the whole row - why not try just copying the bit you need?

Comment: Instead of `a <> ""` you could achieve same effect by filtering and copying requiqred rows. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672484/how-to-delete-every-row-in-a-range-that-contains-data/47672944) (first answer). The code is deleting but you can also copy it.

Comment: I found/solved the problem, there was conditional formatting applied to a cell far out of range, so the page break preview saw that cell as not blank, and so the print range also included that cell far away :)

Also included suggestions above, thanks :)